# Find the vector equation of the plane that is spanned by $\vec{v}=[-2, 1, \frac{1}{2}], \vec{w}=[4, -\frac{1}{5}, -1]$ and contains $[0, -1, 4]$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I was given the following problem:

> Find the vector equation of the plane that is spanned by $\vec{v}=[-2, 1, \frac{1}{2}], \vec{w}=[4, -\frac{1}{5}, -1]$ and contains $[0, -1, 4]$

> Note: Clearly $[a, b, ...]$ denotes a vector.

I'm really unsure about my procedure and wanted to see if it's correct. Here's what I attempted to do.

---

$I$. $\vec{n}:=[-2, 1, \frac{1}{2}] \times[4, -\frac{1}{5}, -1] = [-\frac{9}{10}, 0, -\frac{18}{5}]$ is a vector normal to $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$. This means the cartesian equation of the plane that is spanned by $\vec{v}, \vec{w}$ is $-\frac{9}{10}x +0y-\frac{18}{5}z=c$. Because $(0, -1, 4)$ is a point in the plane we know

$$-\frac{9}{10}(0) -\frac{18}{5}(4)=c \iff c=-72$$

from which follows that the plane is defined by the equation

$$-\frac{9}{10}x +0y-\frac{18}{5}z=-72$$

or equivalently

$$-\frac{1}{10}x -\frac{2}{5}z=8$$

$II.$ Clearing for $z$ we have $z= 20-\frac{1}{4}x+0y$. From this we can build the vector equation of the plane as

$$\vec{g}(t)=[0, 0, 20]+t_1[1, 0, -\frac{1}{4}] + t_2[0, 1, 0]$$

---

I have no clue whatsoever about whether this is correct or not and could really use some validation/correction. The reasoning seems clear:

$i$. We find a cartesian equation for the plane, and ensure we are satisfying the condition that the plane passes through the point via finding the appropriate $c$.

$ii.$ We clear the cartesian equation for one of the variables ($z$ in this case) and build a vector equation that ensures the satisfaction of the "cleared" cartesian equation.

Does this make sense?

Comment: The method itself is valid, though it is highly circuitous. You seem to have made a mistake when calculating $c$, however. The simple way of finding a vector equation would be simply to use the vector form of a plane: $\vec{r}(t_1, t_2) = \vec{a} + t_1 \vec{d}_1 + t_2 \vec{d}_2$, where $\vec{a}$ is a vector in the plane, and $\vec{d}_1, \vec{d}_2$ are two linearly independent direction vectors parallel to the plane. Here, $\vec{a} = [0, -1, 4]$ and $\vec{d}_1, \vec{d}_2 = [-2,1,1/2],[4,-1/5,-1]$.

Comment: Just like you divided by $9$ to simplify, you could also multiply by $10$ or $5$ to simplify.

Comment: @TheoBendit When you say $\vec{a}$ a vector in the plane, you mean the position vector of a point in the plane, right? That's... Way simpler than what I did. Thanks

Comment: @lafinur Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 1):

One more way:
Let the point [0,-1,4] be $\vec a$, then the eq. of the plain is $(\vec v \times \vec w).(\vec r-\vec a)=0$.Or one may also write
$(\vec v \times\vec w).\vec r=[\vec v, \vec w, \vec a].$

Edit:

Other (vector) eqn is
$(\vec r - \vec a)=p\vec v + q \vec w$, where $p,q$ are scalars.

Comment: I understand this, but that that's the normal equation of the plane, not the vector equation. Right?

Comment: You may see my edit.